# Calling Method with and without Parentheses in Python

Tags: python, python-2.x

I've realized that some methods should be called with `()`, while others can't.  How can I check, using IPython e.g., whether to use parentheses or not?  For example the following file `scratch.py`

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.randn(5)

print arr.sort, "\n"
print arr.sort(), "\n";
print arr.shape, "\n";
print arr.shape(), "\n";
```

produces this output:

```
<built-in method sort of numpy.ndarray object at 0x7fb4b5312300> 

None 

(5,) 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scratch.py", line 8, in <module>
    print arr.shape(), "\n";
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 6):

Those are not methods, those are [**properties**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property). The [**descriptor**](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) is invoked behind the scenes by Python itself.

Comment: Or they may just be attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Methods in Python are always invoked with a ().
Best way to check if something is a method is to read the documentation of the library.